# React Native Location Services “nearby” Implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, location-services

I’m building a React-Native social media app with a feature that allows you to find other users who are nearby. I know React Native has location services capabilities, but I’m not sure how I would implement this type of background location tracking. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have built something like this by now, but still, I will try to help you out here.

1. Get user's current location and store it in ES/MongoDB. You will do this for all other users as well. So, now you have a data source containing all users' current locations.
2. Now do a query to ES/MongoDB to get users with their current locations in X miles radius of your current user's location.

Voila you have this feature ready.

PS: To get user's current location you can use the `react-native-location` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem through the library officially supported by React-native.

[react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation)

[Links you can refer to for troubleshooting](https://reactnative.directory/?search=geolocation)